# PowerBuilder Data store limitation

Tags: powerbuilder

Currently i am using PB 11.2, i am facing datastore issue. Data store not supporting more than 800k records and got disconnected application.

how do we resolve this issue?

Comment: Elaborate more on your issue, describe what is currently happening

Comment: Based on the date range i am pulling the records from database using datastore and exporting to CSV files.
earlier the datastore records count is less than 8 lakhs records i dont have any issue, but now datastore records count is more than 8 lakhs records applications got terminated.